# Can't access Scala private val with reflection

Tags: java, scala, reflection

Spark has this [BisectingKMeansModel](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/BisectingKMeansModel.scala#L43) with a `root` field that I want, but it isn't exposed! I tried to get it through reflection but I get a `NoSuchFieldException`:

```
Field rootField = model.getClass().getDeclaredField("root");
rootField.setAccessible(true);
node = (ClusteringTreeNode) rootField.get(model);
```

I even tried enumerating the fields:

```
for (Field f : model.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```

But it isn't listed. I'm not familiar with Scala, what's going on here?

Comment: From the point of view of Java `BisectingKMeansModel` probably has a public method `root()`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it - the `root` field is on the wrapped class.

```
ClusteringTreeNode node;    
try {
    Field parentField = model.getClass()
            .getDeclaredField("org$apache$spark$ml$clustering$BisectingKMeansModel$$parentModel");
    parentField.setAccessible(true);
    org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.BisectingKMeansModel parentModel =
            (org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.BisectingKMeansModel) parentField.get(model);
    Field rootField = parentModel.getClass().getDeclaredField("root");
    rootField.setAccessible(true);
    node = (ClusteringTreeNode) rootField.get(parentModel);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

For future googlers, at least until this gets fixed: Spark BisectingKMeansModel hierarchy tree dendrogram